# Nullable bool or bool with default value in action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nullable, default-value

Perhaps a small question but im curious.

What is favored?

In a controllers action, when passing arguments, when and how should they be used?

```
public ActionResult Action(bool aBool = false)
```

or

```
public ActionResult Action(bool? aNullableBool)
```

I tend to use defualt-value as its a bit more clear and eassier to check, but am i thinking wrong?

Comment: Think whether your column in DB is null or not. If yes, use nullable

Comment: Here's a third way to throw in there: `public ActionResult Action([DefaultValue(false)]bool aBool)` :)

Comment: @Silvermind Yep :) haha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two are not equivalent. In the first example, the caller *must* specify `true` or `false`, if he does not, `false` is used.

In the second line, the caller may provide `true`, or `false`, or `null`. You will need to decide how to handle `null`. That's a third value that you can get. Plus the caller can not omit it. He *needs* to pass a value.

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken, but if you omit the value in the second example it would be null.

Comment: @Silvermind That's incorrect, the type is nullable **not** optional, subtle difference, but with nullable you need to specify something, even if it's just null.

Comment: @Silvermind, if you want to do this you will must write :
public ActionResult Action(bool? aNullableBool = null)

Comment: @mattytommo Thanks, I stand corrected. I was confused with `?aNullableBool=&etc` so without a value in the querystring.

Comment: I took this as a answer, but with adding knowledge from @hjalmar-z by adding it as a nullable bool with default null.

Comment: @mattytommo Just getting back a while later, but I remembered this because I'm working with this now. Perhaps we were discussing something else, but for a querystring `MVC` does not need the parameter to be specified if it is a nullable value, so I revoke my correction.

Comment: wording is a bit odd... saying the user *must* specify... but then `if he does not, false is used` ? Contradiction

Answer (score 4):

The `.HasValue` property of nullable variables can be quite handy sometimes. Having a nullable bool is like having a bool in a bool. Take Chuong Les [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561346/nullable-bool-or-bool-with-default-value-in-action#comment23793600_16561346) with the database, when you read a cell you may want to check that the cell actually holds a value before continuing (and ending up with an error further down the line).

Instead of having to make sure that isn't the case before reading the cell you can use a nullable variable and use `if (aNullableBool.HasValue)` to make sure you have a value before continuing.

That beeing said, unless you run the risk of the variable getting the value `null` you should use a default value.

Answer (score 0):

I think default value in Route configuration will be best.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the role of your bool.

If you want to have a default value or not (default behavior + just one other behavior), so just 2 behavior of this method.

If you want to have a third behavior as a default behavior, you will need to use a nullable bool.

So think about the needs of your method and choose accordingly.